# How do I fit the inner box inside the outer box?

Tags: html, css

So I am attempting to code a fluid layout, and am experimenting with the float tag.
The first step was to develop a simple fluid layout that has two divisions that fill the whole page in width. The blue box has a width of 25%, the color #0076a3. The height is 600 pixel, the green box ha sa width of 75%, the color # 7cc576. The height is 600 pixels. Then I want to add 4 boxes inside the blue box, each has a height for 150 pixels.

Afterwards, I wanted to place those two divisions (that are formed from the left division and right division) at the center of another that has a width of 1200px.
The Problem I am facing is that only I can fit the inner box(blue boxes and green one) inside the outer box(gray one) properly.

```css
#mainDiv {
  width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #c2c2c2;
}
#leftDiv,
#rightDiv {
  height: 600px;
  margin: 0px;
}
#leftDiv {
  width: 25%;
  background-color: #0076a3;
  float: left;
}
#rightDiv {
  width: 75%;
  background-color: #7cc576;
}
#box1,
#box2,
#box3,
#box4 {
  height: 150px;
  clear: both;
}
#box1 {
  background-color: #6dcff6;
}
#box2 {
  background-color: #00bff3;
}
#box3 {
  background-color: #00aeef;
}
#box4 {
  background-color: #0076a3;
}
```

```html
<div id="mainDiv">
  <div id="leftDiv">
    <div id="box1"></div>
    <div id="box2"></div>
    <div id="box3"></div>
    <div id="box4"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="rightDiv"></div>
</div>
```

This final output should look like this:

[image: Final output]

Comment: This question needs more clarification - I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to achieve. Do you want to put the blue box with the 4 internal boxes, inside the green box?

Comment: i'm not sure what the "inner" and "outer" boxes are. please provide more info

Comment: @rockmandew no i want to put the blue boxes and the green box inside the gray one

Comment: Give me a minute - @Predator44

Comment: you cannot center via margin:auto whatever that floats, inline-block or inline-tble can stand side by side and be centered via text-align http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LpbVEq

Comment: @GCyrillus is there a way to use only float to achieve the result? without using the inline-block or inline-table?

Comment: @Predator44 no floats goes off the natural flux and will stick to the further left or right ... just like it is suppose to. You may wrap them in element using display:table properties or with latest browser the flex properti wich is really powerfull and flexible

Comment: @JRulle unfortunatelly, the desired output and the question is not clear cause if div 100% + 2 floatting at 25 and 75 we have 100 and no need to center anything . or there is a real question (being really clarified) or there is none but  big misunderstanding from OP ;)  .... maybe the background-color should be set on body

Answer (score 1):

Okay so I got it working but For some reason I can't seem to find where the extra whitespace is coming from on either the blue or green box but there is a little space between them - which is while you'll see I adjusted the width of the blue box to be 24.66% which allows them to be on the same line - I also took away the floats and clears - you want to use "inline-block" for this.

Here is a Fiddle for you to play with: https://jsfiddle.net/rockmandew/Lkkuzmh9/

```
#leftDiv {
    width: 24.66%;
    background-color: #0076a3;
    display:inline-block;
}
#rightDiv {
    width: 75%;
    background-color: #7cc576;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Thank you for trying to answer my question, but this isn't my desired output and its my fault I didn't clarify further. I have attached what the final result should be in the main question.

Answer (score 1):

The `float: left` should be applied to both `#leftDiv` and `#rightDiv`.

EDIT:
I modified my answer to include a `div#container` to position the floated elements within the grey box parent.

```css
#mainDiv {
  width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #c2c2c2;
}
#container {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#container:after {
  content: ".";
  display: block;
  height: 0;
  clear: both;
  visibility: hidden;
}
#leftDiv,
#rightDiv {
  height: 600px;
  margin: 0px;
  float: left; /* float moved here */
}
#leftDiv {
  width: 25%;
  background-color: #0076a3;
}
#rightDiv {
  width: 75%;
  background-color: #7cc576;
}
#box1,
#box2,
#box3,
#box4 {
  height: 150px;
  clear: both;
}
#box1 {
  background-color: #6dcff6;
}
#box2 {
  background-color: #00bff3;
}
#box3 {
  background-color: #00aeef;
}
#box4 {
  background-color: #0076a3;
}
```

```html
<div id="mainDiv">
  <div id="container">
    <div id="leftDiv">
      <div id="box1"></div>
      <div id="box2"></div>
      <div id="box3"></div>
      <div id="box4"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="rightDiv"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hahaha great answer, I didn't even realize he didn't apply the float to the other element >.<      ----   Good catch

Comment: I didn't clarify my question enough, I have edited it with the desired output. Sorry for any inconvenience.

Comment: @Predator44 http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LpbVEq you can set a width or a max + min width as in the demo

Answer (score 1):

What if you just add `padding` to `#mainDiv`? Like this:

```css
#mainDiv {
  height: 600px;
  width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 200px 200px 200px;
  background-color: #c2c2c2;
}
#leftDiv,
#rightDiv {
  height: 600px;
  margin: 0px;
}
#leftDiv {
  width: 25%;
  background-color: #0076a3;
    float: left;
}
#rightDiv {
  width: 75%;
  background-color: #7cc576;
    float: left;
}
#box1,
#box2,
#box3,
#box4 {
  height: 150px;
}
#box1 {
  background-color: #6dcff6;
}
#box2 {
  background-color: #00bff3;
}
#box3 {
  background-color: #00aeef;
}
#box4 {
  background-color: #0076a3;
}
```

```html
<div id="mainDiv">
  <div id="leftDiv">
    <div id="box1"></div>
    <div id="box2"></div>
    <div id="box3"></div>
    <div id="box4"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="rightDiv"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: unfortunately, it does not fit the gray box perfectly from all angles, since the values we provided in the padding are fixed.

Comment: what do you mean all angles? like when resizing?

Comment: The blue and green box aren't centered properly in the gray one. Kindly check my question and see the desired output. I want both the left and right margin to be exactly of the same width

Comment: I don't see how the left and right margins aren't the same width since they are specified. To me it looks just like your picture

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code.

```css
 #mainDiv {
        height:700px;
        margin: 0 auto;
      }
      #container{
        height:90%;
        background-color: #c2c2c2;
        padding: 0 100px;
      }
      #leftDiv,
      #rightDiv {
        height: 500px;
        margin: 0px;
        float: left;
      }
      #leftDiv {
        width: 25%;
        background-color: #0076a3;
      }
      #rightDiv {
        width: 75%;
        background-color: #7cc576;
      }
      #box1,
      #box2,
      #box3,
      #box4 {
        height: 125px;
        clear: both;
      }
      #box1 {
        background-color: #6dcff6;
      }
      #box2 {
        background-color: #00bff3;
      }
      #box3 {
        background-color: #00aeef;
      }
      #box4 {
        background-color: #0076a3;
      }
```

```html
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatibile" content="IE-edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="netguru recruitment task">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="mainDiv">
      <div id="container">
        <div id="leftDiv">
          <div id="box1"></div>
          <div id="box2"></div>
          <div id="box3"></div>
          <div id="box4"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="rightDiv"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```